# Pass optional argument to angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("validator", validator);

function validator() {

  var validator = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    require: "^validation",
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return validator;

  function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
  }

}
```

And I am applying it as follows:

```
<span validator></span>
```

How can I pass an optional argument to the directive? Something like:

```
<span validator="arg value"></span>
```

or is it better?

```
<span validator validator-arg="arg value"></span>
```

I then need, inside link function, to check if the argument is null or not.

Comment: What is the value to pass? A string? Something else? Anyway, the attributes argument of the link function allows getting the value of the validator attribute.

Comment: The value will be a string ... But somehow I need to pass such a value other times I will not pass anything

Comment: So, check the value of the attribute, and act accordingly.